# The use of "touch" and "touch on" in context

Tags: prepositions

> This issue touches (**on**) personal beliefs, and beliefs always trumps facts.

In this [video](https://youtu.be/vBiBiCdlXes) at 2 minute and 16 second, a speaker used the version with *on*. But what if I omit the preposition, will it be correct in the context? If not, then why?

Comment: Just wait until you also run into "touch base" and "touch in".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume it would not be correct since it is a phrasal verb which has a different meaning from the usual

*to touch - to move your fingers over something*

As a phrasal verb, **touch on** means *to mention something while you are talking or writing.*

> The conversation was going so well until Marco decided to touch on
>   Diana's death

In the context above, the conversation went from good to bad because Marco mentioned/talked about Diana's death.

Answer (score 6):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/touch_on_(or_upon)) says

> **touch on (or upon)**
>
> PHRASAL VERB
>
> 1 Deal briefly with (a subject) in written or spoken discussion.
>
> *he touches upon several themes from the last chapter*

Saying "This issue touches personal beliefs" doesn't really make sense. The sentence needs a slight correction too, to be one of the following:

> This issue touches on personal beliefs, and belief always trumps facts.
>
> This issue touches on personal beliefs, and beliefs always trump facts.

NB. The video won't play past 0:46.